# Chapter 2 Lemma 6.1 in Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a noetherian integral separated scheme which is regular in codimension one and let $f \in K^x$ where $K$ is the function field of $X$. Let $Y$ be a prime divisor contained in some affine open subset $U$ of $X$. 
Since $f$ is regular on $U$, we have $v_Y(f) \ge 0$. Hartshorne then writes that $v_Y(f) > 0$ if and only if $Y$ is contained in the closed subset of $U$ defined by the ideal $Af$ in $A$.

I do not understand the last statement.

I am not sure about the notation $Af$. I know that the function field $K$ is isomorphic to the quotient field of $A$. The notation $Af$ looks like the ideal generated by $f$ in $A$. However, I don't see how this will be an ideal of $A$.

Comment: It is the ideal generated by $f$ in $A$. $f$ is in $A$ because $A$ is the ring of regular functions on $U = \operatorname{Spec} A$, and $f$ is regular on $U$.

Comment: Since $f$ is regular $f \in \mathcal{O}_x(U)$. I am slightly confused how this implies that $f \in \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A}(\operatorname{Spec} A) = A$?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_X(U) = A$!

Comment: Ok. I think I am having a hard time showing that for any open affine subset $U$, $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is equal to $\mathcal{O}_U(U)$.

Comment: I guess I can see that since $\mathcal{O}_X(U) = \lim_{V \supset U} \mathcal{O}_X(V)$.